# Group first match only using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying t match first occurrence only like this 
Let's say  we have 2 divs :

```
<div>
  <span class="time">2016</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="time">2017</span>
  <span class="time">2018</span>
</div>
```

I want to get 
2016
2017

Since second div has 2 it will get first one only  and so on and here is an example to make it easier.

Example

https://regexr.com/3rma6

How to match first date only in this url ? What should I add to regex to do that
Is that possible ?

Comment: Please include what you have already tried.

Comment: I added url for what I have achieved till now  https://regexr.com/3rma6

Comment: @ahmad you should mention exact html snippet, so we can achieve exact regex . Even I can see you have different html snippet in question and link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let input = `<dt class="buyer-feedback">

<span>Всё как описывал продавец,  доставка до 
города Калининграда долгая!</span>

</dt>

<dd class="r-time">21 Apr 2018 23:37</dd>
                </dl>

<div class="f-additional-title" data-spm- 
anchor- 
id="0.0.0.i1.5dc4OM5cOM5coS">Additional 
Feedback </div>
                <dl class="buyer-additional- 
review">

<dt class="buyer-addition-feedback"></dt>
<dd class="r-time" id="0.0.0.i4.5dc4OM5cOM5coS">22 Apr 2018 08:19
</dd>
                </dl>

</div>`;
let s = input.match(/(?<=<\/dt>\n*\s*<dd.*>).*(?=\s*\n*<\/dd>)/g);
console.log(s);
```

**Try this**

What this regex does is to check if it is preceded by the closing tag of dt followed by the element dd.

```
let input = `<dt class="buyer-feedback">

<span>Всё как описывал продавец,  доставка до 
города Калининграда долгая!</span>

</dt>

<dd class="r-time">21 Apr 2018 23:37</dd>
                </dl>

<div class="f-additional-title" data-spm- 
anchor- 
id="0.0.0.i1.5dc4OM5cOM5coS">Additional 
Feedback </div>
                <dl class="buyer-additional- 
review">

<dt class="buyer-addition-feedback"></dt>

<dd class="r-time" data-spm-anchor- 
id="0.0.0.i4.5dc4OM5cOM5coS">22 Apr 2018 
08:19</dd>
                </dl>

</div>`;
let s = input.match(/(?<=<\/dt>\n*\s*<dd.*>).*(?=<\/dd>)/g);
```

Output = ["21 Apr 2018 23:37", "22 Apr 2018 
    08:19"]

Comment: That's really cool but it was an example can you apply it on real one please https://regexr.com/3rma6    I added the url in thread but no one opened it.  I will be so grateful for you.

Comment: That's amazing I have been trying for 5 hours and I thought it's not possible I will try to figure how your regex works.  I appreciate your help ^^.

Comment: No problem sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one for the schema in your link. It finds `<div>`, then skips all `<span>|<dl>|<dt>|<\span>|<\dl>|<\dt>`, and then matches the first `<dd>`. It might not work if there are multi-line `<span>`. It may also break if any `<div>` is missing `<dd>`, but only if `<dd>` can exist outside of a `<div>`. It will also break if `<span>, <dl>, or <dt>` can have children. There is probably a fix for these issues, but it really depends on how badly you need it.

```
<\s*div\s+[^>]+>\s*(?:<\s*dt\s+[^>]+>\s*|<\s*dl\s+[^>]+>\s*|<\/\s*dl\s*>\s*|<\s*span\s*>[^<]+<\/\s*span\s*>\s*|<\/\s*dt\s*>\s*)+<\s*dd\s+class\s*=\s*"r-time"\s*>([^<]*)<\/\s*dd\s*>\s*
```

Comment: The schema is in this url https://regexr.com/3rma6   for the code it only match 2017

Comment: Should work now. There are a lot of extra \s* that are probably unnecessary but I added them for safety.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').each(function(){
console.log($(this).children("span:first").text())
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="time">2016</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="time">2017</span>
  <span class="time">2018</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="time">2019</span>
  <span class="time">2020</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="time">2021</span>
  <span class="time">2022</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="time">2023</span>
  <span class="time">2024</span> 
  <span class="time">2025</span>
</div>
```